# android onClick for views that return different parameters

Tags: java, android, onclick

I personally like using onClick to structure my code like having

```
protected void onCreate( ....

    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fit_list_btn_add);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

def onClick (View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn1:
```

Now, when I have different views, their onClickListeners return different parameters, like

```
 onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

returns position and id.

How can I capture all those in on onClick method? And if that doesnt work, what is the best way to deal with this.?  I am not very familiar with java. Is there a best practice way in java to structure that?

Comment: What is the problem with onListItemClick?? I understand you write single onclick method and use it with different buttons and inside implementation of onClick you find what is the id of the view tapped and take actions :) That ensures all the actions being captured in one method :) but why would you do anything like that for listview???

Comment: If you have 5 to 10 buttons in one screen and you write 1 onclick listener implemetation rather than 10 makes sense :) but you wont find so many listview's in single activity :) so writing a single onListItemClick for multiple listview's seriously doesn't make any sense :) Most importantly onListItemClick in itself is not of much help as you can see it tells what is the position of item on which it was tapped but wont give the item itself :) You need to fetch the item on your own from adapter based on the position :) and usually every listview will have its own adapter (data source)

Comment: and each adapter might providing a different types of data better altogether different object itself so writing single implementation of onListItemClick for multiple listview's is ruled out there :) I personally write seperate onListItemClick for each listview in its activity or adapter depending on the scenario and I create seperate implementation of onListItemClick for each listview :) Hope I made a little sense there :)